# Passing `-l<libname>` vs passing `lib<libname>.a` directly to linker?

Tags: c++, c, unix, linker

Suppose I have two files

```
// a.c
int a() {return 1;}

// b.c
int a();
int b() {return a();}
```

and I compile them to `a.o` and `b.o`, respectively.

In an attempt to make an executable or shared library, one can call `gcc a.o b.o -o libab.so -shared`. But I also noticed that one can also call `gcc b.o -L. -l:a.o -o libab.so -shared` to generate (apparently) the same output. To my surprise, even running `gcc a.o -L. -l:b.o -shared` results in a library that has both `a()` and `b()`. (Shouldn't linker discard the unused library `b.o` since `a.o` does not depend on it?)

The latter two presumably pass `a` in as if `a.o` was a library. Now if I run `ar rcs liba.a a.o`, `gcc b.o -L. -l:liba.a -shared` and `gcc b.o liba.a -shared` both run without any problem and give the same output.

However, I have also seen case where this trick doesn't work and results undefined references. My question is therefore as the titles says: what are the differences between passing an object as a library and as a normal object file, and are there any differences when it comes to C++?

*The problem arose in a much larger project. Sorry for lacking mcve because I can't seem to isolate the problem.*

Comment: I think, there is some misunderstanding there. static libraries are merely an archive of .o files, so there is no surprise that linker can treat a single .o file as a library. By itself it should not lead to any undefined behavior. I am afraid, you'd have to work more on isolating the test case.

Comment: @SergeyA, I understand `.a` is an archive of `.o` files. For simplicity let's just say `.a` is `.o`, the question is then how is `gcc a.o b.o` different from `gcc a.o -L. -l:b.o`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am saying, there is no real difference. Also, `-l:<lib>` is the syntax I am not familiar with, and I can't find it referenced anywhere. I assume it works, but I am pretty sure this is not conventional.

Comment: `results undefined references` - what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @KamilCuk, it literally just means `undefined reference to <function>` by the linker.

Comment: "what are the differences between passing an object as a library and as a normal object file" run gcc in verbose mode and check what it passes to the linker under the hood in both cases and see if there are any differences

Comment: @Slava, I've run `ld` directly and saw no difference in some cases and failures in other cases. I believe it's not a `gcc` thing, but I will give it a try.

Comment: If that is the case then you should ask about `ld` not `gcc` or `g++`

Comment: You know that the order of libraries matter in linker invocation? Maybe this could be an answer? The order of symbols doesn't matter when using .o files, while for .so files it's important?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I do, so you're saying only the order matters not how it is passed in?

Comment: It's like connected? The order matters because .so files are passed using `-l` switch.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I guess that's why, at least very likely. When passing `.o` directly the objects were before external libraries, while when using `-l` they were appended at the end, and my crude experiments can confirm this. Can you please elaborate on the order difference between `.o` and `.so`?

Comment: But if you specify the `.a` files with `-l` switch, it will be the same, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How does] Passing `-l<libname>` vs [differ from] passing `lib<libname>.a` directly to linker?

Passing `-llibname.so` will make GNU linker traverse the library only once when searching for a symbol (when not after `--whole-archive` option). Specifying `.a` file directly to the linker makes it search for every symbol in all the object files inside the `.a` file for every symbol, not only once.

From the [GCC Linker options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) (emphasis mine):

> -llibrary
>
> ...
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.

From [binutils ld options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/Options.html#Options):

> -l namespec
>
> ...
>
> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the archive again.

Comment: *Passing `-llibname.so` will make GNU linker traverse the library only once*...  *Specifying .a file directly to the linker makes it search for every symbol in all the object files inside the `.a` file*.  I'm not seeing the distinction, and in fact I don't believe there *is* a distinction -- I've always believed that specifying `-lx` versus (say) `/lib/libx.a` behaved identically.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the differences between passing an object as a library and as a normal object file, and are there any differences when it comes to C++?

That depends on the implementation.  In the most general sense, Unix-style linkers such as you are asking about *search for* objects named via `-l` options in a library search path, whereas if you name a file directly, you must specify the exact file.

Additionally, if you use an `-l` option to specify a file to link then, in the general case, the linker constructs a filename from the argument by prepending "lib" and appending ".a", or in some other way, such as by searching also or instead for ".so" files.  (The GNU linker that you appear to be using provides an exception to this behavior when the first character of the argument is `:`.  In that case it takes the rest of the argument as an exact file name, and searches for that.)

Many linkers also accept explicit library names specified on the command line (e.g. `libfoo.a` instead of `-lfoo`), so these need to be able to determine what type of file each is.  Normally this is by examining the file, not by relying on its name.  And GNU `ld`, at least, extends this file type detection to files specified via `-l` options.

The order in which objects and libraries are specified on the command line, by whatever specific form, matters to typical linker implementations.  For example, [the docs for GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/index.html) specify that

> options which refer to files, such as ‘-l’ or ‘-T’, cause the file to
>   be read at the point at which the option appears in the command line,
>   relative to the object files and other file options

which is important because

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.

But of course

> You may list the same archive multiple times on the command line.

The docs are not altogether clear on this, but empirically, the use of the term "archive" in the above is significant.  It is effectively only *archive* files -- static libraries -- to which the "searched only once" provision applies.  To a first approximation, the relative order of different ordinary object files and shared libraries on the GNU linker's command line, no matter how designated, does not impact symbol resolution.

So yes, it does matter whether you specify regular object files or static archives or shared libraries to the (GNU) linker, and their order matters to some extent, but the *manner* in which you specify them does not matter.

> I have also seen case where this trick doesn't work and results undefined references.

With the GNU linker, that will be because of genuinely missing libraries or objects, or because of an unsuitable order of static archives relative to other object files or archives.  Some other linkers are more sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Short answers:

1. The `-L` and `-l` options provide a shortcut for locating library archives (and shared libraries).  But once you've used `-l` to locate a library (in the standard locations, or in a location specified by `-L`), the reading of that library is identical to the way it would be read if you specified its filename (e.g. `/lib/libx.a`) at the same spot on the command line explicitly.
2. When you specify a single object (`.o`) file, the entire contents of that file get loaded unconditionally.  When you specify a library archive (`.a`) file, only those objects within it that are necessary (to satisfy outstanding undefined references) are loaded.